# spring mvc: cleanest way for more than one submit button?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a a form and I'd like a next and back button inside it.
What is the cleanest way to do this in spring mvc? Just give the input type submit a name and value and check for that in my controller?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you use Spring 3, you can distinguish between controller methods using `params` attribute:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "next" value = "Next" />
<input type = "submit" name = "back" value = "Back" />
```

.

```
@RequestMapping(..., params = "next")
public ModelAndView next(...) { ... }

@RequestMapping(..., params = "back")
public ModelAndView back(...) { ... }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the default submit button must be the first one in the html. @skaffman's approach does not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that, yes. Alternatively, don't use true submit buttons. Instead, use vanilla HTML buttons, with attached javascript handlers which later the form's target, and then programmatically submit the form.

Which one is "cleaner" depends on your point of view.

Comment: True, but using javascript for that creates a dependency on javascript which I'm not too fond of when it's not required. I prefer to use javascript to enhance the functionality of an application.