# How to have multiple buttons and treat them accordingly in a Spring MVC form?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

By using Spring MVC + Maven + Hibernate I'm trying to build a Spring MVC form that has both an "Add To Cart" button, as well as a "Add to Favourites" button. Whenever one button is pressed, the other one returns null as shown in the code below.

Both buttons are *type=submit* and I'm treating them in the code below. The problem I'm having is that the "Add to Favourites" case is always resulting into an uncaught exception (redirecting me to the "Internal Error" page).

I'm wondering if maybe there's an elegant way to treat each button press in a form separately, without having lots of if - statements for each button.

The HTML file has the following items declared in the form's structure:

```
<c:if test="${empty readOnly}">
                        <input type="number" value="1" name="quantity" class="input-mini"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="addToCart"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"><jsp:text /></i> Add</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="favourite"><jsp:text /> Favourite This!</button>
</c:if>
```

And I'm using the following Controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
      public String submit(HttpServletRequest request, Model uiModel) {

        init(uiModel);
        String id = request.getParameter("product-id");
        String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");

        if(!request.getParameter("addToCart").toString().equals(null))
        {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(id) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(quantity)) {
              shoppingCartServiceLocal.addToShoppingCart(shoppingCart, id, quantity);         
            }
        }

    if(!request.getParameter("favourite").equals(null))
    {
        //ADD TO FAVOURITE
    }
        return "redirect:/items/" + id;
 }
```

I might be missing something obvious as I'm still learning these. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366268/spring-mvc-cleanest-way-for-more-than-one-submit-button

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. You can add that as an answer and I'll accept it or I'll just delete the question.

Comment: @axtavt does spring handle the issues with ie? where submit buttons submit their inner html? I believe pre IE9?

Comment: @kmb385: It doesn't matter because this solution uses names of submitted parameters, not their values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `param` attribute to specify which method to use for which button.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "addToCart")
public String addToCart(HttpServletRequest request, Model uiModel) {
    //your code
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "favourite")
public String addToFavorites(HttpServletRequest request, Model uiModel) { 
    //your code
}
```

Comment: The true beauty of this solution is that you can have more than one method mapped to the same url, and the one with the specified parameter will be called.